# How to make a string store 32000 characters in java?

Tags: java

I am very new to Java.

I want to store an image pixels inside a string. But right now if the image has more than 4000 pixels I am not able to store all the characters in a string.

How can I define a string to store more characters?

Comment: Why on earth would you like to store image pixels in a string instead of using a byte or integer array?

Comment: I want to see if a specific pattern is found in the image pixels. which I can easily find using the "substring" method if I have a string. I cannot do this if I store it in an integer or byte.

Comment: @Blacklabel, could you elaborate a little more? Show an example of what you are trying to do with those pixels. There might be a better way.

Comment: @Blacklabel, substring will only work in a very limited amount of cases none of which are very interesting.  You should consider a datatype holding a _number_  (or even a boolean if you have flattened to black and white), and then just bite the bullet and write the necessary loops in full.

Comment: @Darin. I basically want to find for a string say "Hello" is found in the last bit of the image pixels. I want to extract every pixel of the image and store the last bit alone in a string. I will convert "Hello" into binary and store into another string. Now I will use the substring function to see if the word is present in the image or not. :). Hope I explained clearly

Comment: What would that string be doing in image pixels?

Answer (score 2):

What is the error you get? `java.lang.String` is as far as I know only bound by memory. You can increase your VM's heap size with the `-Xmx` argument.

```
java -Xmx1024m my.Thingy
```

Will set 1024 megabyte memory to your java heap size.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in eclipse?

Comment: Changing the heap size for eclipse, will only affect things whilst running your code inside eclipse - this is typically not how you are going to deploy things. Having said that, you are perhaps doing some data processing using eclipse. Check out http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: in Eclipse "run configuration" you can set the JVM options for starting up your program, if you are running it from within Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to store a byte array in string, the proper way to do it is by encoding it in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) has the `Base64` utility class that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Strings can have up to 2 billion characters.  Perhaps you can explain what happens when you try to store all the bytes of the image in a String?  Perhaps you are running into encoding problems as String is not intended for storing binary data.

The simplest/safest way to store binary data in a String is to use a literal translation rather than use an encoding which can mange the data.

```
byte[] bytes
// takes each byte as is with 0 as the "high" byte.
String string = new String(bytes, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your main concern is about storing large amount of characters in a String, as far as I know, the only constraints for it are the String length() method, which returns an int (so you are limited to MAX_INT chars) and you JVM memory, which you can change as pointed by Martin. To do that inside eclipse, you must edit your current run configuration, and you'll find a tab named "Arguments" where you can put all arguments (except the java command itself).

About finding the word 'Hello', my bet would be using a char array and write the loops myself. String behaviour in Java may be affected by locale and char encoding, so it could mess up your result. Anyway, what you suggest sounds to me like steganography. There is in fact some literature about techniques for finding wether an image contains data hidden with steganography and extracting it, so maybe you should focus your research on steganalysis (not sure if this is the correct word).

Cheers.